# Show members of AD group in Power Apps gallery items

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am working on an app that  fetches Azure AD groups based on amount value and stores the names of the groups in SharePoint column (Person/Group type).

In the Gallery, I have multiple rows in the following format.

[image]

The AD Groups in the gallery are fetched from SP column (person/group type) using the code:

ThisItem.ADGroup1.DisplayName

ThisItem.ADGroup2.DisplayName

In the gallery items, is it possible that I can show the members of each group?
For example, there are 3 users in UserGroup1, so I want to show the members of that group (emails of group members or display names)

So the gallery view can be

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is definitely possible, but the right implementation depends on what you want to do with the names.

See, the group members are a sub-table in your gallery item, so you could either:

1. Nest another gallery and display the group members there
2. Use an HTML Text control and the Concat() function to display members, for example as links to send them emails: `Concat('AD Group 1'.value,"<a href='mailto:" & email & "'>" & displayName & "</a>", "; ")`

Galleries have more functionality, HTML Text is perhaps easier.

To merely show the member names:

`Concat('AD Group 1'.value,displayName, "; ")`

To iterate the members and send individual emails:

`ForAll('AD Group 1'.value,Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(email,"(subject)","(body)")`

Comment: Thank you for the details dear. Actually, I need to use the AD members names and email address on two places.
1- to show the member names from groups in the gallery items (each row)
2- to include member names and emails in HTML templates and to send emails to each member separately.

Comment: extended my answer based on your comment

Comment: Concat('AD Group 1'.value,displayName, "; ")

I replaced this code with the following but it is still not working

Concat(gallery1.selected.adgroup1.value, .value,displayName, "; ")

Comment: Try this: Concat(gallery1.selected.adgroup1.value, displayName, "; ")   you had an extra ', .value' in the formula.

Comment: sorry my bad ... it was actually to get members
Concat(gallery1.selected.adgroup1.value, .value,members , "; ")

output i am trying is to get the members of adgroup1 as below (so it can show the members of the selected AD group)

member1 name; member2 name ...

Comment: Concat(gallery1.selected.value, displayName, "; ") should work. If your gallery is a collection of AD groups, then '.value' is the collection of group members. This formula gives you the semicolon separated names as text. To show the members in another gallery, you should just do this: Gallery2.Items = Galler1.Selected.Value

Comment: I have stored AD group information onStart property of app .. Code is 

Set(varL2opgc2Usermembers, AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("952cg52b-0dfc-41d6-8u29-6e11bb87a9d9").value);

Comment: got it. I just replaced gallery1.selected.value, displayName in the concat function with the variable name and fetched the right information. Thank you so much for your help and support.